# Empty output file from Scrapy for both CSV and JSON

Tags: python, json, csv, scrapy

So I have been working on this project for my school and I came across this problem where there is no output in the results file.  I tried to find solutions for it. None of them seemed to work for me.

here is my spider code for Scrapy:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_craigslist.items import ScrapyCraigslistItem


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'craigslist'
    allowed_domains = ['vancouver.craigslist.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?']
    rules = (
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=(r'vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa.*'),
            deny = (r'.*format\=rss.*')
        ),
            callback="parse_items_1",
            follow= False,
             ),
        )

    def parse_items_1(self, response):
        self.logger.info('You are now crawling: %s', response.url)
        items = []
        hxs = Selector(response)
        contents = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='rows']/*")
        for content in contents:
            item = ScrapyCraigslistItem()
            item ["title"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span/a/span/text()").extract()[0]
            k = content.xpath("//p/a/@href").extract()[0]
            item ['ad_url'] = 'https://vancouver.craigslist.ca{}'.format(''.join(k))
            item ["post_date"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span/time/text()").extract()[0]
            item ["post_date_specific"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span/time/@datetime").extract()[0]
            item ["price"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span[@class='l2']/span/text()").extract()[0]
            item ["location"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span[@class='l2']/span[@class='pnr']/small/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            return item
```

for my items.py script it is:

```
import scrapy


class ScrapyCraigslistItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    post_date = scrapy.Field()
    post_date_specific = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()
    ad_url = scrapy.Field()
```

for my pipelines.py script it is:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.titles_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['title'] in self.titles_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.titles_seen.add(item['title'])
            return item
```

for my settings.py it is:

```
BOT_NAME = 'scrapy_craigslist'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['scrapy_craigslist.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scrapy_craigslist.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy_craigslist.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 10,

}

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.2.1) Gecko/20120616 Firefox/12.2.1 PaleMoon/12.2.1"
```

And finally this is the result that I get in the command line for both JSON and CSV

```
/home/logan/Desktop/scrapy-craigslist-master/scrapy_craigslist/spiders/craigslist_scrapy.py:1: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
/home/logan/Desktop/scrapy-craigslist-master/scrapy_craigslist/spiders/craigslist_scrapy.py:2: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
/home/logan/Desktop/scrapy-craigslist-master/scrapy_craigslist/spiders/craigslist_scrapy.py:3: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: scrapy_craigslist)
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_craigslist.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'load.csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_craigslist.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_craigslist', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.2.1) Gecko/20120616 Firefox/12.2.1 PaleMoon/12.2.1', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy_craigslist.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline']
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-04-15 14:12:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-04-15 14:12:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa> (referer: None)
2017-04-15 14:12:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa> (referer: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa)
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [craigslist] INFO: You are now crawling: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sale_date=2017-04-15&sort=upcoming> from <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sort=upcoming>
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sort=priceasc> (referer: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa)
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?s=120> (referer: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa)
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [craigslist] INFO: You are now crawling: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sort=priceasc
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [craigslist] INFO: You are now crawling: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?s=120
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sale_date=2017-04-15&sort=upcoming> (referer: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa)
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sort=date> (referer: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa)
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sort=pricedsc> (referer: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa)
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [craigslist] INFO: You are now crawling: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sale_date=2017-04-15&sort=upcoming
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [craigslist] INFO: You are now crawling: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sort=date
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [craigslist] INFO: You are now crawling: https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?sort=pricedsc
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2728,
 'downloader/request_count': 8,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 8,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 241678,
 'downloader/response_count': 8,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 7,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 15, 21, 12, 46, 796319),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
 'log_count/INFO': 13,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 7,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 8,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 8,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 8,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 8,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 15, 21, 12, 44, 841317)}
2017-04-15 14:12:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

sorry for the long request, Thanks.

Comment: have you debugged your code? is maybe `contents` an empty list?

Comment: the code is supposed to work perfectly, but when you try outputting it. it just doesn't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page does not contain the XPath you specify for `contents`. So the loop never executes and there is never returned any item.

```
contents = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='rows']/*")
for content in contents:
    ...
    return item
```

Probably the site changed the structure of the HTML-Code for some reason. And the code you're using may have worked before that change but needs now some adjustments to the new structure.

To find out which adjustments are needed you can use the developer mode of your browser. With Firefox you could use the Add-Ons FireBug and FirePath.